# how to prevent mocha from exiting process with status 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have written a simple node.js application and now I want to add some tests. For now I have only some example Tests to test my Gitlab-CI, SonarQube and Mocha, which i am using for testing.

Now my problem is, that I want to parse the results from mocha (reporter is the sonar-mocha-reporter). My problem is that mocha exits the process with status 1 if a test is failing. That means gitlab-ci is breaking the build and will not run to the end. So i can not parse the results like it should.

Is there a way to configure mocha to not break my build so that it only saves the results in this xml file?

I am starting mocha with:

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha -R mocha-sonar-reporter --recursive --no-exit
```

and in my package.json i have the configuration:

```
"config": {
    "mocha-sonar-reporter": {
      "outputfile": "build/reports/tests/TEST-mocha.xml"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps can you just do:

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha || true
```

If it fails, it will then return `true`, and be successful.

Answer (score 1):

Add parameter `silent` to command line. For example:

`npm run test --silent`